# How to get first and last word from lines in C?

Tags: c

I have a problem with code. I want to take first and last words from each lines from txt file. I wrote this code for now:

```
void StartEnd(char * word)
{
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen("linie.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
      printf("! ");
      return;
    }
    char store[MAX_LINE];
    
    while (fgets(store, MAX_LINE - 1, fp)){
    char * FirstWord = strtok(store," ");
    char * LastWord;  
    char * token = strtok (store," ");
    while (token != NULL){
    LastWord = token;
    token = strtok (NULL," ");
}
    printf("%s\n",LastWord);
    }
    
    fclose(fp);
 
}
```

It is working for last word but only if i dont use FirstWord with strtok and i dont know why :(.
I would be grateful for any answer. Thanks!

Comment: You should use a debugger, perfect tool for your problem.

Comment: Also, add #includes and fix indentation

Comment: @lulle this is only part of code, i have a problem with this part of code

Comment: You should not do strtok (store." ") twice as store has been modified with the call for FirstWord. Always copy string in a new string before doing strtok as the string is modified by strtok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On a first call, the function expects a C string as argument for str,
> whose first character is used as the starting location to scan for
> tokens. In subsequent calls, the function expects a null pointer and
> uses the position right after the end of the last token as the new
> starting location for scanning.

On subsequent calls to `strtok`, you are supposed to pass a `NULL` pointer. Doing that makes the function work properly:

```
void StartEnd(char * word)
{
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen("linie.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
      printf("! ");
      return;
    }
    char store[MAX_LINE];

    while (fgets(store, MAX_LINE - 1, fp)){
        char * FirstWord = strtok(store," ");
        char * LastWord;
        char * token = strtok (NULL, " ");
        while (token != NULL){
            LastWord = token;
            token = strtok (NULL," ");
        }
        printf("%s\n",LastWord);
        printf("%s\n",FirstWord);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Keep in mind that `fgets` reads `n-1` characters or until it encounters a `newline` or `EOF` character. however a newline character is also considered a valid character and stored in the string. That means `LastWord` may end with a `newline` character. To fix that, pass `" \n"` instead of `" "` to strtok. Then both a newline and a blankspace are considered delimiters.

Comment: Btw, i need to print whole line of text only if my first word or last word have given word in them. Should i use function strstr?

Comment: The problem is that strtok modifies the original string, it replaces the delimiters with null characters effectively cutting the original string in multiple strings ("tokens"). If you need to print the string, you should create a copy of it before calling strtok the first time on that string.

Comment: Use strcmp to compare two strings. strstr checks if one strings appears in another, if it does, it it doesnt, it returns NULL. Lets say the first word is "ABCDEFG" and you should print the full line, if the first word is "ABC", when you use strstr, it will find that "ABC" is contained in "ABCDEFG" and wont return a NULL pointer.

Comment: while (fgets(store, MAX_LINE - 1, fp)){
    char * FirstWord = strtok(store," ");
    char * LastWord;  
    char * token = strtok (NULL," ");
    while (token != NULL){
    LastWord = token;
    token = strtok (NULL," ");
}
    if(strcmp(FirstWord,word) == 0 || strcmp(LastWord,word) == 0){
        printf("%s\n",store);
    }
Something like this?

Comment: Read my first comment again. If you print store, it will only print the first word of store.

Comment: So i need to copy store to another char, and print this copied char?

Comment: yup, create a copy of it before calling strtok